# Rails: Wrong time is displayed with using bootstrap3-datetimepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datetimepicker

My app uses `bootstrap3-datetimepicker` to display time (hour and minute).

Time can be saved in table correctly, and can be displayed in `show` view.

But wrong time is displayed when I try to edit.
Although the minite is correct, the hour is wrong (always 8 PM).

For example,

DB: `04:01:00`

View: `8:01 PM` (format is `LT`)

I expect to be `4:01 AM`.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'event_form'%>
```

**_event_form.html.erb**

This happen both`:start_at` and `:end_at`.

```
<%= form_for([@room, @event]) do |f| %>

   ...

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="form-group">
           <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
             <%= f.text_field :start_at, :class => 'form-control'%> #this line
             <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
             </span>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT'
          });
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
                    <%= f.text_field :end_at, :class => 'form-control'%> #this line
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'LT'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

   ...
```

I follow https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats

**schema**

```
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "start_at"
    t.time     "end_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.integer  "room_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "category"
    t.integer  "ccy"
    t.decimal  "amount"
  end
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
 ...
  def edit
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
    @event = @room.events.find(params[:id])
  end
 ...
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any advice.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the datetime picker is expecting you to set the value in the same format. That is to say, the value you pass to the picker should be '4:01 AM', not '04:01:00'.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @MrWillihog. Although I tried to use `l(:start_at)` in order to reflect the format settings in yml file, the following error is displayed. `I18n::ArgumentError (Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. :start_at given.):`. This may be another issue but it would be appreciated if you could give me any hint.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way, but I have something like this in my javascript: `$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment(myDate).utc().format(DATE_FORMAT));`. Probably worth waiting for someone to come along with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the date in the DB is in UTC but the datepicker is displaying the date in your local timezone.  You can disable the timezone for the datepicker as follows

```
var options = {};
options['timeZone'] = '';
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(options);
```